# Listing Windows phone devices connected to computer

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, usb

I would like to ask if there is a way to recognize all **Windows Phone 8** devices connected to my computer?

I have Windows Phone SDK installed and there are several services running on my computer but I don't know if I get information for connected devices running on Windows Phone?

Thank you in advice.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at these modules:

```
using Microsoft.SmartDevice.Connectivity;
using Microsoft.SmartDevice.Connectivity.Interface;
using Microsoft.SmartDevice.MultiTargeting.Connectivity;
```

You can get the list of devices using

```
var devices = new MultiTargetingConnectivity(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.LCID).ToList();
```

Whatever you want to do, you can look at the [source of the WP Power Tools application](http://wptools.codeplex.com/).